# Trying to automate with capybara-angular & capybara-ng gems - Help & Examples.-

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, middleman

**Hello!**

I'm trying to automate the following piece of code:

```
<form class="form ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-email" ng-controller="SubscribeController" subscribe-directive="">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-email ng-touched" ng-model="subscription.email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-disabled="working || subscription.done" type="email">
<button disabled="disabled" type="submit" ng-class="{'working': working}" ng-disabled="working || !subscription.email || subscription.done" ng-click="submit(subscription.email)">
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="submitBtn">Click</span>
</button> <p ng-bind-html="callback_message" class="msg ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="callback_message"></p>
</form>
```

Although I can reach them when executing Javascripts commands on the page (Using @javascript tag with the cucumber set up), I cannot make it to work due to the property that the input field has, since only changes to enabled when entering the email manually or even when I trigger to change the state, but when I click the button, the email that I entered seems not to be sending over.

I'm using Cucumber + Capybara + Rake + Rails and some other Gems, and the site was built with Middleman.

**Here's the code I've implemented with pure JS to test:**

```
page.execute_script("$('input[type=email]').val('#@random_email}').trigger('blur')")
page.execute_script(" $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false).trigger('click') ")
```

When included the `capybara-ng` gem and adding the line

```
include Capybara::Angular::DSL
```

I got:

```
cucumber
uninitialized constant Capybara::Angular (NameError)
```

and I've included the `spec/spec_helper.rb` but I'm getting that the file could not be loaded!

Can someone point me to any good example and usage of any or both mentioned gems? or how could I test Angular? do someone have a reason that this won't work?

I'm kinda of a newbie in the Ruby world so please let me know if the question is too silly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"uninitialized constant Capybara::Angular (NameError)" indicates some trouble in initialization order.

I just created small example, which may help you:

https://github.com/kikonen/capybara-ng/blob/master/spec/dummy/features/test.feature